# Are Dynamic Prepared Statements Bad? (with php + mysqli)

Tags: php, sql, dynamic, eval, prepared-statement

I like the flexibility of Dynamic SQL and I like the security + improved performance of Prepared Statements.  So what I really want is Dynamic Prepared Statements, which is troublesome to make because bind_param and bind_result accept "fixed" number of arguments.  So I made use of an eval() statement to get around this problem.  But I get the feeling this is a bad idea.  Here's example code of what I mean

```
// array of WHERE conditions
$param = array('customer_id'=>1, 'qty'=>'2');
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

$types = ''; $bindParam = array(); $where = ''; $count = 0;

// build the dynamic sql and param bind conditions
foreach($param as $key=>$val)
{
    $types .= 'i';
    $bindParam[] = '$p'.$count.'=$param["'.$key.'"]'; 
    $where .= "$key = ? AND ";
    $count++;
}

// prepare the query -- SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE customer_id = ? AND qty = ?
$sql = "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ".substr($where, 0, strlen($where)-4);
$stmt->prepare($sql);

// assemble the bind_param command
$command = '$stmt->bind_param($types, '.implode(', ', $bindParam).');';

// evaluate the command -- $stmt->bind_param($types,$p0=$param["customer_id"],$p1=$param["qty"]);
eval($command);
```

Is that last eval() statement a bad idea?  I tried to avoid code injection by encapsulating values behind the variable name $param.

Does anyone have an opinion or other suggestions?  Are there issues I need to be aware of?

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question title a bit, so others can find your question more easily.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it is dangerous to use `eval()` here.

Try this:

- iterate the params array to build the SQL string with question marks `"SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE p1 = ? AND p2 = ?"`
- call `prepare()` on that
- use `call_user_func_array()` to make the call to `bind_param()`, passing in the dynamic params array.

The code:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), array($types)+$param);
```

Comment: Be careful with `array($types)+$param`. If $param is an array with an index of 0, then that value in $param will get dropped in favour of $types, and you will get an error for having fewer variables than indicated in your string.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Answer (score 0):

I made a filter function which recives an array an asociative array like $_GET:

In model class I've defined a couple of properties including the schema:

```
private $table_name = "products";

protected $schema = [
    'id' => 'INT',
    'name' => 'STR',
    'description' => 'STR',
    'size' => 'STR',
    'cost' => 'INT',
    'active' => 'BOOL'
];
```

Then a filter method which recive an asociative arrays of conditions:

```
function filter($conditions)
{
    $vars   = array_keys($conditions);
    $values = array_values($conditions);

    $where = '';
    foreach($vars as $ix => $var){
        $where .= "$var = :$var AND ";
    }
    $where =trim(substr($where, 0, strrpos( $where, 'AND ')));

    $q  = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table_name} WHERE $where";
    $st = $this->conn->prepare($q);

    foreach($values as $ix => $val){
        $st->bindValue(":{$vars[$ix]}", $val, constant("PDO::PARAM_{$this->schema[$vars[$ix]]}"));
    }

    $st->execute();
    return $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

And works great to filter results

Answer (score -1):

You don't really need prepared statements and bound arguments, because you can always use mysql_real_escape_string(). And you're right; dynamically generated SQL is far more flexible and valuable.

Here's a simple example using the regular mysql_* interface:

```
// Array of WHERE conditions
$conds = array("customer_id" => 1, "qty" => 2);

$wherec = array("1");
foreach ($conds as $col=>$val) $wherec[] = sprintf("`%s` = '%s'", $col, mysql_real_escape_string($val));

$result_set = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $wherec);
```

Of course, this is a simplistic example, and to make it useful you have to build and refine it a lot, but it shows the ideas and it's really very very useful. For example, here is a completely generic function to insert a new row into an arbitrary table, with the columns filled with the values from an associative array and completely SQL-injection safe:

```
function insert($table, $record) {
    $cols = array();
    $vals = array();
    foreach (array_keys($record) as $col) $cols[] = sprintf("`%s`", $col);
    foreach (array_values($record) as $val) $vals[] = sprintf("'%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($val));

    mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO `%s`(%s) VALUES(%s)", $table, implode(", ", $cols), implode(", ", $vals)));
}

// Use as follows:
insert("customer", array("customer_id" => 15, "qty" => 86));
```

Comment: Bound parameters adds additional security beyond escaping. It's a good practise to use them.

Comment: Could you please show me what additional security they offer then? What kind of attack would you be protected from with bound parameters vs. my solution?

Because if you're referring to a programmer's ability to make mistakes, I'd rather have the more powerful tools than constraining tools.