# Inserting string into PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, security, sql-injection

I'm working with a wrapper method to MySQL that uses Statement, I want to change this to PreparedStatement to enhance security, unfortunately, this method requires that arbitary SQL be allowed as a parameter, such as "WHERE id=5".

Can I allow this somehow with a PreparedStatement?

If not, can you suggest another way that I can sanitize the database input to prevent SQL Injection?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Sorry, that wasn't clear, the whole "WHERE id=5" bit is changeable every time, not just the 5.

Comment: `arbitary SQL` does that refer to the '5' or to the full `WHERE` fragment?

Comment: @leonbloy Full WHERE fragment, edited the original post to make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean whether you can make dynamic PreparedStatements, well, you can, as long as you have control over the alternatives. Eg (pseudocode) :

```
  sql = "SELECT * FROM EMAIL WHERE TYPE = ?";
  if(haveId) 
    sql += " AND id=?";
  st = createPreparedStatement(sql);
  st.setString(1,type);  
  if(haveId) 
     st.setString(2,id);
```

Of course, this get complicated if you queries have many variations. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201468/are-dynamic-prepared-statements-bad-with-php-mysqli).
And if your queries are totally arbitrary (if you user can type the "WHERE" itself)...  you are in trouble.

Comment: The user himself can't enter the WHERE bit, but there would be far too many variations to possibly do it the way you suggest. 

How would you protect against SQL injection in this instance?

Comment: If they are variations in the WHERE conditions, pls see the link I posted. Elsewhere, I'm afraid I'd need more info.

Comment: They're usually WHERE conditions, but really, it could be anything.

Comment: That can be ugly -even dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Provide it some question marks:

```
PreparedStatement s = new PreparedStatement("SELECT X FROM Y WHERE ID = ?");
s.setString(1, "123456");
s.execute();
// ...
```

More info here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0):

yes, you would put the following:

```
"WHERE id=?";
preparedStatementInstantce.setInt(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a PreparedStatement you would replace your injection values with a question mark

```
WHERE id=?
```

Then you can use the setters on the PreparedStatement object to insert them.

```
pstmt.setInt(1, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also make the prepared statement along the lines of

```
WHERE (id = ? OR false = ? ) AND (name = ? OR false = ?) --etc
```

and put the false = ? flags to true when you got the corresponding parameter to go with it