# Dynamic Prepared Statements - Does this open security holes?

Tags: php, mysql, security, prepared-statement

This is similar to this question - [Are Dynamic Prepared Statements Bad? (with php + mysqli)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201468/are-dynamic-prepared-statements-bad-with-php-mysqli), however since it is 4 years old I wanted to get a more upto date answer.

I've written a class which, although I haven't tested it on more copmlex sql queries, it has worked without fail on simple sql queries, however I'm not sure if doing so has bypassed one of the main reasons for prepared statements - security.

I have made use of the `call_user_func_array` which was easy enough with the `bind_param` statements however with the `bind_result` was a little trickier. I originally used `get_result` however the host I've gone with doesn't have `mysqlnd` available, but I managed to get around using the metadata. This is the full class I have written.

Do you think this is secure?

The passed in values are:

- `$sql` is the passed in sql statement:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? AND created_timestamp > ?
  ```
- `$mysqli` is the mysqli connection
- `$para` is the placeholder in the prepared statement:

  ```
  array ($types = 'ii', 23, 1235376000)
  ```

The class:

```
class crudModel {
    function ps($sql, $mysqli, $para) {
        //this function should work for just about any simple mysql statement
        //for more complicated stuff like joins, unions etc,. we will see
        if ($prep = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
            call_user_func_array(array($prep, 'bind_param'), $this->makeValuesRef($para, $mysqli));
            $prep->execute();
            $meta = $prep->result_metadata();
            while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
                $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
            }
            call_user_func_array(array($prep, 'bind_result'), $parameters);
            while ($prep->fetch()) {
                foreach ($row as $key=>$val) {
                    $x[$key] = $val;
                }
                $data[] = $x;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }

    function makeValuesRef($array, $mysqli) {
        $refs = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $array[$key] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($value); //i don't think escaping is necessary, but it can't hurt (??)
            $refs[$key] = &$array[$key];
        }
        return $refs;
    }
}
```

Comment: From where does `$sql` originate?

Comment: If you use PDO instead of mysqli, you're code will become more portable, as the PDO object layer is compatible with most DBMS not only MySql.

Comment: $sql from another class. for the time being i've only used simple sql statements to test this class with joins being the most complex things i've used on it. i.e. $sql = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN others ON (users.id = others.user_id) WHERE others.id = ?"

Comment: Have just started playing around with PDO so will look into that as well

Comment: But from where does `$sql` ***originate***?  Is it something that is 100% under your control and into which you can be certain no malicious SQL has been injected?  Or does some part of it, perhaps a table or column identifier, originate from outside of your application?

Comment: ok sorry i understand now. yes i'll only be passing into that class from within my own application. at least at the moment. i guess if i were to take sql statements from an outside sql application i'd have to put further security measures into that but i can't imagine needing to do that at the time.

Comment: Then I see nothing harmful with what you are doing; the problem in the question to which you linked was the OP's use of `eval()`.  On the contrary, what you're doing is very safe and sensible; however you should remove the call to `real_escape_string` (it will lead to records being stored with escape characters).

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here isn't a dynamic prepared statement. You're just putting some syntatic sugar on top of the MySQLi API (which sucks).

In short, there aren't really any security concerns present from the code you've shown here. In fact, this sort of practice is quite good, because it makes it easier to verify that you're doing it correctly later (since the MySQLi API sucks).

So you're fine. I would worry about the areas you're generating the queries, and ensuring that you're not accidentally putting user-data into them without white-listing...